# Importing Redux Reducer throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm building a simple App with React Native using Expo. But I'm struggling with getting redux to work.

I created an reducer:

```
import { ADD_PHOTO } from "./photo-actions";
import Object from "../models/object";

const initialState = {
  photos: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_PHOTO:
      const newObject = new Object(
        new Date().toString(),
        action.photoData.title
      );
      return {
        photos: state.photos.concat(newObject),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is my action

```
export const ADD_PHOTO = "ADD_PHOTO";

export const addPhoto = (title) => {
  return { type: ADD_PHOTO, photoData: { title: title } };
};
```

This is the object for my reducer:

```
class Object {
  constructor(id, title) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
  }
}

export default Object;
```

My App.js file is not working and throwing the following error every time I want to import "photosReducer" --> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.defineProperty')

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";

import PageNavigator from "./navigation/PageNavigator";
import photosReducer from "./store/photo-reducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  photos: photosReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PageNavigator />
    </Provider>
  );
}

styling...;
```

My dependencies:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
 ...
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.6.0",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^6.2.0",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
...
```

I do not see why importing photosReducers is throwing that error.

Comment: You redefined Object in your "This is the object for my reducer"- an import part of Javascript. Basically you say "Ignore all this this stuff: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object, The Object will now be super dumb with no methods". Jokes aside, redefining a built-in elements is almost never a good idea. Whatever you need the Object for, rename it to MyReduceObject or something

Comment: Wow, I would have never figured that out. Obviously my naming was quite dumb. I'll try to fix it. Thanks for quick response!